# Add Items to RibbonCombobox with "for" loop

Tags: c#, winforms, ribbon, ribbon-control

I'm sorry for I'm not good at English.
this is my code:
Code winform

```
for (int i = 10; i < 70; i++)
            {
                RibbonButton rbtn = new RibbonButton();
                rbtn.Text = i.ToString();
                ribbonComboBox2.DropDownItems.Add(rbtn);
            }

            //ribbonComboBox2.SelectedItem = ribbonComboBox2.DropDownItems[0];
            //-----------Tạo danh sách font chữ
            System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection fonts = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();
            foreach (FontFamily family in fonts.Families)
            {
                RibbonButton rbtn = new RibbonButton();
                rbtn.Text = family.Name.ToString();
                ribbonComboBox1.DropDownItems.Add(rbtn);
            }
```

I didn't see any items when clicking the RibbonCombobox.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: I'm working with winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are using for the Ribbon control since I don't think that is native to winforms, but my guess is that when you say "I didn't see any items when clicking the RibbonCombobox." you are seeing that the combobox has items but they are displayed as blanks. This is most likely caused from the combobox not having the `DisplayMember` property set.

```
for (int i = 10; i < 70; i++)
{
    Button rbtn = new Button();
    rbtn.Text = i.ToString();
    ribbonComboBox2.Items.Add(rbtn);
    ribbonComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Text";
}


System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection fonts = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();
foreach (FontFamily family in fonts.Families)
{
    Button rbtn = new Button();
    rbtn.Text = family.Name.ToString();
    ribbonComboBox1.Items.Add(rbtn);
    ribbonComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
}
```

To use the `DisplayMember`, you set it equal to the name of the property that you want shown in your combobox. The name of the property should come from the items in the combobox. I used `Button` and `ComboBox`since I didn't know what you were using but I'm willing to bet that it will work just fine for you. The `DisplayMember` is set to "Text" because you want to display the `Text` property of your button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `RibbonCombobox` does not have the `DisplayMember`

Comment: @TinTin Where are you getting the RibbonCombobox from?

Comment: By that I mean, what namespace and/or dll are you using?

Comment: I write the same software as "wordpad".
I use "ribbon control" from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working for you then. Using the same code in your question works fine for me.

Comment: @TinTin It wouldn't be appropriate to add it to the answer as it isn't part of the solution nor am I able to add it to a comment. I can walk you through the same steps though. 1. Add a Ribbon to the from. 2. Add a RibbonTab to the Ribbon. 3. Add a RibbonPanel to the RibbonTab. 4. Add a RibbonComboBox to the RibbonPanel. I then used the exact code in your question to populate the RibbonComboBox. Note that I use your code in the `Load` event for the form. Are you doing the same?

Comment: I did the same thing

Comment: I put that code in the "formload" event but it still does not work

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: From the link you provided I selected the "Download Ribbon_Release_2018_03_19" and I grabbed the dll that was in the "Ribbon_Release_2018-03-19_NET461" folder.

Comment: I changed to another version and the problem was resolved. Thank you so much!